# SQL issue get all rows with dates 14 days from now or less

Tags: mysql

Say i have an expiration date field, called expires_at, and lets say i have 1 row with 1 value whitch is 10 days from today.

How do i query all rows where expires_at is no more then 14 days from now or before that?

Something like this i asume

```
SELECT * FROM column WHERE CURDATE() +14? >= expires_at
```

Can i add 14 days to the current date and just get all the days before CURDATE() + 14?

I am not awesome at SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_gtable
WHERE expires_at <= CURDATE() + interval 14 day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE expires_at < DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```